# how to get the absolute path of a file in the same the same directory as the parent folder, from the child file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

here is what I mean, my file structure looks like this:

> main folder
>
> > app.js 
> > child folder
> >
> > > fille.js

I want to get the absolute path of app.js from file.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming you are inside `file.js` and want to get the absolute path of `app.js`, with `child folder` being fixed, you can use [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths):

```
const path = require( 'path' ).join( __dirname, '..', 'app.js' )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:
You can try `path.resolve`

try:

```
resolve = require('path').resolve
resolve('../../app.js')
```

You will need to provide the relative path and it will give you absolute path. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let path = __dirname.substr(0,__dirname.lastIndexOf('/'));
```